# docker: Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?

Tags: docker, ubuntu-16.04

I installed Docker CE from the official docker site on Ubuntu server 16.04.4 LTS, Release: 16.04, Codename: xenial. I can not find the `/var/lib/docker` file even after I install docker on my machine. When I try to run an Ubuntu container for example with:

```
docker run -it ubuntu
```

an error message:

```
docker: Can not connect to the Docker daemon at unix: ///var/run/docker.sock
```

Is the docker daemon running?

Comment: How did you install docker?

Comment: @NicoHaase I use the official tutorial from docker : https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/docker-ce/ubuntu/

Comment: Can you confirm that docker is properly installed and the dockerd daemon process is up?

Comment: The tutorial contains different ways of installing. Which one did you use? And did you start the container using `sudo`?

Comment: @Yuankun no I can not confirm it because I think it's not normal that docker is installed and the folder / var / lib / docker does not exist in my directories.

Comment: @NicoHaase i use the installation with use a repository to define docker and yes i start the container with sudo. i execute the commands with root.

Answer (score 3):

First you have to ckeck if the docker service is running `service docker status`

if it's not running, start it: `service docker start`

then you can use `docker run ....`

Comment: I do it. Sorry but i can't paste the output because i'm in ubuntu server 16.04.4 LTS but i have an error message in red mentionned : "Failed to start Docker Application Container Engine" and in line Process:
 5641 ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd -H fd:// -s overlay2 (code exited, status=1/FAILURE). Anyone have a suggestion please i spent many time in this issue...

Comment: Still getting "Docker is not running" after tried "service docker start".

Answer (score 0):

Please try with sudo : `sudo docker run -it ubuntu`

Comment: Helbert i try to do it but i have the same issue.

Comment: The daemon process isn't running. Follow the instructions for setting up docker!